# how to stop receiving duplicate mail?

Tags: php

When a user press submit button I received 7 copies duplicate mail in my administrator email box. How can I receive only one mail. here is my code.

```
$MyCoupon = 0;
$cResult=mysql_query("select * from codes WHERE status='active'");
while($cRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($cResult)){
    if($_POST['coupon_used']==$cRow['code'] || $_POST['invoice']=="invoice"){

            $coupon = ($_POST['coupon_used']!="" ? $_POST['coupon_used'] : "invoice");

            $aRes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adverts` WHERE `ad_id`='".$_POST['ad_id']."'");
            $aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aRes);

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE `adverts` SET `message_status`='awaiting approval',`target_impressions`='".$_POST['ad_impressions']."',`recurring`='".$_POST['ad_recurring']."',`coupon_used`='".$coupon."',`POIO`='".$_POST['ad_POIO']."' WHERE `ad_id`='".$_POST['ad_id']."'";         
            $updateResult=mysql_query($updateQuery) or die("Unexpected error: record could not be added.".mysql_error());
            include_once("update_ads_from_database.php");

            //SEND EMAIL to CC
                $to = "mymail@gmail.com";
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: Do-Not-Reply@domain.com';
            $subject = 'New self-serve mail';
            $message = "The following self-service ad has just been submitted:<br>";
            $message .= $aRow['contact_name']."<br>".$aRow['contact_phone']."<br>".$aRow['contact_email'];
            $message .= "<br><br>Description:".$aRow['description']."<br>Content:".stripslashes($aRow['value'])."<br><br>";
            $message .= "Click <a href=\"http://www.domain.com/admin/approve_self_ad.php\">here</a> to approve it.";
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            $goodCoupon++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending one email for each coupon code found on the database. You could create a single email message, and send it after the loop:

```
$MyCoupon = 0;
// Init empty message body
$message = "";
$cResult=mysql_query("select * from codes WHERE status='active'");
while($cRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($cResult)){
    if($_POST['coupon_used']==$cRow['code'] || $_POST['invoice']=="invoice"){
        $coupon = ($_POST['coupon_used']!="" ? $_POST['coupon_used'] : "invoice");
        $aRes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adverts` WHERE `ad_id`='".$_POST['ad_id']."'");
        $aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aRes);
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE `adverts` SET `message_status`='awaiting approval',`target_impressions`='".$_POST['ad_impressions']."',`recurring`='".$_POST['ad_recurring']."',`coupon_used`='".$coupon."',`POIO`='".$_POST['ad_POIO']."' WHERE `ad_id`='".$_POST['ad_id']."'";        
        $updateResult=mysql_query($updateQuery) or die("Unexpected error: record could not be added.".mysql_error());
        include_once("update_ads_from_database.php");

        // Add info on current row to email body
        $message .= "The following self-service ad has just been submitted:<br>";
        $message .= $aRow['contact_name']."<br>".$aRow['contact_phone']."<br>".$aRow['contact_email'];
        $message .= "<br><br>Description:".$aRow['description']."<br>Content:".stripslashes($aRow['value'])."<br><br>";
        $message .= "Click <a href=\"http://www.domain.com/admin/approve_self_ad.php\">here</a> to approve it.";

        $goodCoupon++;
    } // end if
} // end while

//SEND EMAIL to CC
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Do-Not-Reply@domain.com';
$subject = 'New self-serve mail';
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```